# Hibernate: Can I use @ManyToMany to map enities of two tables only using one element of a composite key?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, join

I have the following two tables:

[image]

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "zip_codes_germany")
public class ZipCodeArea implements Serializable {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name="zip_code")
    private String zipCode; 
    @Column(name = "city")
    private String city;
    @ManyToMany
    private Set<TravelAgency> agencies;
```

and

[image: travel_agencies]

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "travel_agencies")
public class TravelAgency implements Serializable {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "city")
    private String city;
    @Column(name = "ceo")
    private String ceo;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "travel_agency_zip_codes", joinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "city", referencedColumnName = "city"),
                @JoinColumn(name = "name", referencedColumnName = "name") }, inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "zip_code"))
    private Set<ZipCodeArea> zipCodeAreas;
```

filled with some data. Where **travel_agencies** has a composite key from columns `name` and `city` and **zip_codes_germany** has the primary key `zip_code`.

I already have the following data in my tables:

[image]

[image]

When loading the travel agency "Nice Guys Company" I'd want it to contain a set with all `ZipCodeArea` elements belonging to the city "Freiburg im Breisgau". So the following test should run through:

```
@Before
public void init() {
        try {
            SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Failed to create hibernate session: ", e);
        }
    }

@Test
public void testManyToMany() {
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<TravelAgency> cq = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(TravelAgency.class);
    Root<TravelAgency> root = cq.from(TravelAgency.class);
    cq.select(root).where(criteriaBuilder.like(root.get("name"), "Nice Guys Company"));
    List<TravelAgency> result = session.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    assertFalse(result.isEmpty());
    assertFalse(result.get(0).getZipCodeAreas().isEmpty());
    }
```

The problem is, that my many to many declaration does not map city to city hence the second `assertFalse` method fails. Is there a way to fix this?

I've tried the following in the `TravelAgency` class

```
@ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "travel_agency_zip_codes", joinColumns = 
            @JoinColumn(name = "city", referencedColumnName = "city")
            , inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "city", referencedColumnName = "city"))
    private Set<ZipCodeArea> zipCodeAreas;
```

but that led to the following Exception:

```
aused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: referencedColumnNames(city) of ZipCodeArea.zipCodeAreas referencing TravelAgency not mapped to a single property
    at org.hibernate.cfg.BinderHelper.createSyntheticPropertyReference(BinderHelper.java:333)
```